# AttributeError in my Python program regarding classes

Tags: python, class, subclass, attributeerror

I'm doing an exercise out of the Python book that involves creating a class and a subclass. I am getting the following error when I try to run the program: `AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'name'`, when it tries to go through this bit of code: `self.name.append(name)`

As this is my first time dealing with classes and objects in Python, I'm sure I am making some overt mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked over the documentation for creating classes and writing member functions, and it *looks* correct, but it is obviously not. I want the Customer subclass to inherit the name, address, and telephone attributes from the Person superclass, but it doesn't seem to be doing so?

Here is my code:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.address = None
        self.telephone = None

    def changeName(self, name):
        self.name.append(name)

    def changeAddress(self, address):
        self.address.append(address)

    def changeTelephone(self, telephone):
        self.telephone.append(telephone)

class Customer(Person):

    def __init__(self):
        self.customerNumber = None
        self.onMailingList = False

    def changeCustomerNumber(self, customerNumber):
        self.customerNumber.append(customerNumber)

    def changeOnMailingList():
        if onMailingList == False:
            onMailingList == True
        else:
            onMailingList == False

def main():

    customer1 = Customer()

    name = 'Bob Smith'
    address = '123 Somewhere Road'
    telephone = '111 222 3333'
    customerNumber = '12345'

    customer1.changeName(name)
    customer1.changeAddress(address)
    customer1.changeTelephone(telephone)
    customer1.changeCustomerNumber(customerNumber)

    print("Customer name: " + customer1.name)
    print("Customer address: " + customer1.address)
    print("Customer telephone number: " + customer1.telephone)
    print("Customer number: " + customer1.customerNumber)
    print("On mailing list: " + customer1.OnMailingList)

    customer1.changeOnMailingList()

    print("On mailing list: " + customer1.OnMailingList)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `super(Customer, self).__init__()` as @Pedro Wemeck say

   But there is a problem to note: If you use `python 2.x`, please change as one of the two ways:

   ```
   class Person -> class Person(object)
   ```

   or

   ```
   class Customer(Person):
       def __init__(self):
           Person.__init__(self)
   ```

   `super` can be only used in new-style class
2. There is a problem:

   ```
   def changeOnMailingList():
       if onMailingList == False:
           onMailingList == True
       else:
           onMailingList == False
   ```

   you should change to:

   ```
   def changeOnMailingList(self):
       if self.onMailingList == False:
           self.onMailingList == True
       else:
           self.onMailingList == False
   ```
3. You get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'` ，because the `self.name` is None, and can't use `append`, which belongs to `list` object.

You can use `self.name = name` directly.

Comment: Thank you. I caught the error on the `changeOnMailingList()` function, but I didn't realize append couldn't be used here. I just used `self.name = name` like you suggested and now it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass Customer is redefining the `__init__` method without calling the superclass method. This means that your lines in `Person.__init__` creating the name, address and telephone attributes are never executed.

You want your `Customer.__init__` method to call `Person.__init__` at some point. Use Python `super()`.

```
class Customer(Person):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Customer, self).__init__()
        self.customerNumber = None
        self.onMailingList = False
```

Comment: That fixed the previous error, but now I am getting a new one: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'` and from looking around a bit, it's because append() returns None. Is there possibly a more elegant way of writing member functions without append?